# apache2 VirtualHost in Mac OS X home directory

Tags: macos, mac, apache-http-server, macports

I am running Macports apache2 on Mac OS X 10.5.  Whenever I configure a virtual host in the default folder, it works, however when I configure the virtual host in my home directory I get a "403 Forbidden" error.

**How do I configure a vhost in my home directory?**

Here is the configuration that yields "403 Forbidden" when I access "devel.mysite.com":
/opt/local/apache2/conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf:
    
       DocumentRoot "/opt/local/apache2/htdocs"
       ServerName *
       #CustomLog "" common

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  #DocumentRoot "/opt/local/apache2/htdocs/mysite"
  DocumentRoot "/Users/myuser/Sites/mysite"
  ServerName devel.mysite.com
</VirtualHost>
```

The error message in `/opt/local/apache2/logs/devel.mysite.com-error_log`:

```
[Sat Apr 17 19:54:49 2010] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] client denied by server configuration: /Users/myuser/Sites/mysite/
```

When I uncomment the line to make DocumentRoot in `/opt/local/apache2/htdocs/mysite`, it works:
    
       DocumentRoot "/opt/local/apache2/htdocs"
       ServerName *
       #CustomLog "" common

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  DocumentRoot "/opt/local/apache2/htdocs/mysite"
  #DocumentRoot "/Users/myuser/Sites"
  ServerName devel.mysite.com
</VirtualHost>
```

I get no errors or warnings when I start apache, and the only thing that is logged on startup is this (in `/opt/local/apache/logs/error_log`):

```
[Sat Apr 17 19:56:29 2010] [notice] Digest: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Sat Apr 17 19:56:29 2010] [notice] Digest: done
[Sat Apr 17 19:56:29 2010] [notice] Apache/2.2.14 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.14 OpenSSL/0.9.8m DAV/2 configured -- resuming normal operations
```

A few notes:
 * The permissions of /Home/myuser/Sites/mysite is 755, owned by myuser, group is staff
 * Everything else works as expected, until I move the ServerRoot of the vhost to the directory in my home

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to put the directory tag, that match the DocumentRoot path like this :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   DocumentRoot /home/user1/htdocs
   ServerName hostname.com
   <Directory /home/user1/htdocs>
       Order allow,deny
       Allow from all
   </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed my 403 Forbidden Error.
I just upgraded to 10.8 and adding

```
<Directory /home/user1/htdocs>
     Order allow,deny
     Allow from all
</Directory>
```